# Hibernate annotation scanning not working under Gradle 5.4

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, gradle, kotlin

I'm busy converting a maven build into a Gradle build, i got everything running, except that i now see this error whenever i try to run an hql query via Hibernate for all entities that i try to query (running via Maven still works, the pom file is still in the project):

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Account is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Account AS o WHERE lower(o.email)=:email]
```

I have the following dependencies under Maven:

```
    <dependencies>

        ...

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

</dependencies>
```

Under Gradle (Kotlin DSL) it looks similar (although much shorter):

```
dependencies {

    ...

    // hibernate
    val hibernateVersion = "5.2.13.Final"
    implementation(group = "org.hibernate", name = "hibernate-core", version = hibernateVersion)
    implementation(group = "org.hibernate", name = "hibernate-entitymanager", version = hibernateVersion).
        exclude(group = "cglib", module = "cglib").
        exclude(group = "dom4j", module = "dom4j")
    implementation(group = "org.hibernate", name = "hibernate-validator", version = hibernateVersion)
    implementation(group = "org.hibernate", name = "hibernate-c3p0", version = hibernateVersion)
    implementation(group = "org.hibernate", name = "hibernate-java8", version = hibernateVersion)

    ...

}
```

Persistence.xml is pretty standard:

```
<persistence-unit name="default">
        <description>Persistence XML</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <!-- Hibernate Config -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>

            <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="com.application.util.CustomNamingStrategy"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>

            <!-- JDBC Config -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>

            <!-- Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />

            <!-- Batch writing -->
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value = "50"/>
            <!-- if this is switched on fixtures does not want to run for some or other reason -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value = "true"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value = "true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value = "true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Maven uses the standard shade plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>ApplicationApi</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                        <exclude>rebel.xml</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <artifactSet/>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/api.jar</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Whereas Gradle uses shadowJar plugin:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow").version("5.0.0")
    ...
}
```

Although running from IntelliJ doesn't use shade/shadow-jarring to run, so even if i remove shadow / shade jarring, it continues to exhibit the same behaviour.

Something i did notice was the package structure after building, maven has everything under `classes` whereas Gradle splits classes into `java` / `kotlin`

Maven:

[image]

Gradle:

[image]

I'm not sure if the above structure has any impact on annotation scanning.

I've tried adding `<property name="packagesToScan" value="....." />` in persistence.xml for each affected entity with no effect.

Entities are all annotated correctly (as i mentioned, this still runs correctly under Maven)

```
@Entity
@Table
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@BatchSize(size = 50)
class Account(
    email: String,
    ...
```

Any idea why i'm getting this error after switching to Gradle?

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Account is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Account AS o WHERE lower(o.email)=:email]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert (ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert (ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert (ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery (AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery (AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery (AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add the following on the `build.gradle`?

```
sourceSets {
  java {
    main {
      output.resourcesDir = java.outputDir
    }
  }
}
```

To quote from the blog post of [Java - What is gradle missing to map hibernate?](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/cwy/java-hibernate-gradle-what-is-gradle-missing-to-map-hibernate).

> And since Gradle doesn't store the "compiled" resources in the same output directory as the compiled classes, Hibernate doesn't find the mapped entities.

It is the reason why you need to add the above configuration.
And also from Gradle 5.x, `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir`, which config of many blog posts mentioning, is withdrawn. So, you need to use `sourceSets.main.java.outputDir` like on the above.

See also: SourceSetOutput - Gradle DSL Version 5.5 https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html